# How to convert scala.concurrent.Future to RxPromise

Tags: rxjs, scala.js

Given a scala.concurrent.Future[Int] is there a function available to convert this to an RxPromise[Int]?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert by adding the following implicit function:

```
implicit def toRxPromise[T](fut: Future[T]): RxPromise[T] = Observable.fromPromise(fut.toJSPromise).toPromise
```